# Nasty NSPropertyListSerialization Leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, plist

```
NSString *anError = nil;
 id plist;
 plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:rawCourseArray mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&anError];
 if (anError != nil){

  [anError release];
 }
```

The above code causes a memory leak every time I call it.  I am releasing the error but still there is a leak.  I haven't seen any resolution to this issue.  I posted this already and most respond that this is not a leak.  But see here in the leak performance tool:

[image]

I need this fixed because eventually my app crashes.  Any ideas?  Many thanks

Comment: I still need a fix for this leak.  Is there another way I can call NSPropertyListSerialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Used propertyListWithData:options:format:error: with same result. Used NSDictionary initWithContentsOfFile with same result:

Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
NSCFNumber,19   < multiple >    304 Bytes   MediaToolbox    FigRemote_CreatePropertyListFromBinaryPListData

FWIW - I only have dictionaries and arrays and strings in the pList, no numbers.

The issue is not the error object (or string in your method). The issue is not plist above, since it should be autorelease. In the end, I gave up and reimplemented using JSON and:

http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/index.html

==> no more leak.

Best,
Fred

Comment: JSON may be my only option.  :^(

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before.

Basically this is because your `error` variable got released without initiating it. So what you can do is try to init your `NSString *error` to an empty string before releasing it. Or not releasing it at all.

Comment: Tried what you suggested but no luck.