# NSPropertyListSerialization Alternative?

Tags: objective-c, serialization, plist

Is there any code that I can use in place of this code snippet?

```
NSString *anError = nil;
 id plist;
 plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:rawCourseArray mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&anError];
 if (anError != nil){

  [anError release];
 }
```

The code above causes a memory leak which I can't correct.  I try releasing the error but no luck.  Is there another way to serialize an array into plist format without the leak?

Regards,
BX

So I edited the code and it now looks like this but still a leak.  It must be something esle.  I  included the loop after...

```
NSError *error = nil;
    id plist;
    plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:rawCourseArray options:/*unused*/0
                                                       format:NULL error:&error];
    //NSArray *entries = (NSArray *)d;
    NSArray *entries = (NSArray *)plist;

    //for (eachCourse in rawCourseArray)
    for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) 
    {
             //LOOP
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using is obsolete and is about to be deprecated according to the apple docs, you should use `propertyListWithData:options:format:error:` instead

[Linkage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPropertyListSerialization/propertyListWithData%3aoptions%3aformat%3aerror%3a)

Comment: Here is a question I posted a few weeks ago showing the leak in the leak performance tool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675730/nasty-nspropertylistserialization-leak

Comment: Maybe propertyListWithData will stop the leaking... I'll try it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There is no memory leak in that code.  However, there is a potential crash.  You should not `-release` the error object, because you do not own it.</strike>  It turns out that `NSPropertyListSerialization` has a terrible API.  Consider using the [`+[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:options:format:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000942-SW5) variant instead.

Are you sure there's a memory leak here?  What's the minimal amount of code you need to reproduce the leak?

Comment: From the apple docs: "errorString

    Upon return, if the conversion is successful, errorString is nil. If the conversion fails, upon return contains a string describing the nature of the error. If you receive a string, you must release it."

Comment: @Zaky wow, I stand corrected.  Thanks, I'm updating my answer.